# create an dropdownlistfor with overtype functionality mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'd like to create dropdownlistfor that lets the user to type a new value or select a predefined one from a dropdown list.

It is possible to create an editable dropdownlistfor in mvc? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery to turn your select in an autocomplete input with [jQuery Select Autocomplete](https://github.com/gabehollombe/jquery-select-autocomplete). The code to do this is very simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.autocomplete').select_autocomplete();
});
</script>
```

Take a look at a live demo here: http://gabehollombe.github.com/jquery-select-autocomplete/